# postgresql - Why does % not return exact matches?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The query:

```
SELECT users.* FROM "users" WHERE (lower(fname) || ' ' || lower(lname) LIKE '%jeff bat%') LIMIT 25
```

Does not return a user with fname: jeff and lname: bat

But if you run

```
SELECT users.* FROM "users" WHERE (lower(fname) || ' ' || lower(lname) LIKE '%jeff ba%') LIMIT 25
```

With one character off it does return that user. Why does the % LIKE not return exact matches? And how can I update the query to also include an exact match? Thanks

Comment: according to the documentation (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html) % should match zero or more characters

Comment: is it possible that the last character in jeff's name isn't actually a 't'?

Comment: Reduce this to the simplest case and show the output of: `SELECT 'jeff bat' LIKE '%jeff bat%'`

Comment: Your syntax works for me. I would suggest to inverstigate different names, and whether it is really a 't' in 'Bat'. Postgresql 8.4, ubuntu linux, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the exact result by including trim function in your query like below

```
SELECT users.* FROM "users" WHERE (trim(lower(fname)) || ' ' || trim(lower(lname)) LIKE '%jeff ba%')
```

Comment: Why? `%jeff` works without trimming. You repeat `LIKE '%jeff ba%'` which already worked without trimming.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need a trim as @kanchirk said:

That should do the trick or try it this way

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM "users" 
WHERE lower(trim(fname)) LIKE '%jeff %'  
AND lower(trim(lname)) LIKE '%bat%') 
LIMIT 25
```

Answer (score 0):

My own hunch is with kanchirk's diagnosis, with a twist: any chances that case sensitivity is additionally rearing its ugly head and that you should be using `ilike` in addition to a trim?

Answer (score -2):

The % at the end indicates that there are more characters in the "Bat" part of the name. So "Bats", "Batch", and "Batty" would match, but "Bat" wouldn't because it doesn't have anything after the "t". Theoretically the % matches 0+ characters, but it doesn't seem like that's happening here.

Comment: That makes sense. Suggestion on how to get % and exact matches?

Comment: The docs and simple experimentation both show this to be false.  `SELECT 'jeff bat' LIKE '%jeff bat%';` returns true.

Comment: @theexit: How much do you need to match? You can use an underscore to match an individual character (e.g. "LIKE 'Jeff Ba_'). Or you could just do "LIKE 'Jeff Bat'" would match it exactly. Or "LIKE 'Jeff%'

Comment: @frank: Shrug. I agree that's how it's supposed to work, but what else explains the behaviour he's reporting?

Comment: `what else explains` suggest, that you explained something, but IMHO you didn't.

Comment: @user: It fits the behavior exactly, so it's a valid hypothesis. You are saying to the original poster, "You can't be having this error, because **I** don't have it" which isn't terribly helpful.

Comment: It doesn't fit the behaviour exactly. It doesn't fit the behaviour at all. Simple tests reveal, that `%` matches zero characters as well. So you need an explanation why it sometimes work and sometimes not. Did you observe that the `%` at the beginning of `%jeff` matches zero characters?

Comment: @user: I did actually. Maybe leading spaces in the data? I wasn't able to reproduce the error on my own equipment.

Comment: When nobody can reproduce the behavior, the problem is usually the data.